# Mask get wrong value

Tags: google-earth-engine, masking

While trying to see if 2 images share some matching pixels I try to implement the mask() function.

In order to do so I used image1.mask(image2)

Here is an example :

Mask of Image 1 :

[image]

Mask of Image 2 :

[image]

Result :

[image]

So here we can see that the 2 images do not share any matching pixels.
I then use this function to compute the sharing pixel in the lake (geometry : table4 here)

```
function maskInRoi(img){
  return img.set({
    "mask": img.rename("mask").mask().reduceRegion({
      reducer:ee.Reducer.mean(),
      geometry:table4,
      crs:ModisProjection
    }).get("mask") 
  })
}
```

I was waiting to have a 0 value for the mask here but got 0.10 instead.
Do anyone have an idea on how to fix this ?

Full version of my code :
https://code.earthengine.google.com/73b0720ddf59367d77c70ecfb642a612